# Как сделать, чтобы бот выполнял те, методы, которые напишет пользователь? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, long-poll

К примеру, чтобы если пользователь отправит

```
(переменная с токеном).method('messages.send', {'peer_id': id чата, 'message': 'тест', 'random_id': 0})
```

То бот выполнит этот метод, то беж, отправит слово 'тест'

Comment: [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec), [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval). Крайне не рекомендуется использовать, т.к. в таком случае пользователь сможет выполнить **любой** код на сервере, где запущен бот. Лучше определите множество фраз, которые должны "стриггерить" выполнение какого-то фиксированного кода.

Answer (score 0):

Советую использовать `requests.get` для отправки запросов

Так же, думаю, удобнее было бы пользователю отправлять данные в виде

```
method=(метод)
access_token=(токен)
peer_id=(id)
далее остальные агрументы ...
```

Так их будет проще распарсить и отправить запрос

Пример функции для запроса к api с помощью `requests`. Всё же лучше использовать`**kwargs`, но это набросок

```
def call(method_name, parameters):
    url = 'https://api.vk.com/method/{}?'.format(method_name)
    for i in parameters:
        url += '{}&'.format(i)
    response = requests.get(url)
    return response
```